# Get Image from Gallery with Intent

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery

I want to get a image from Gallery with the share command.

My current code is:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        Log.d("Test","Simple SEND");
        Uri imageUri = (Uri)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        }
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
        Log.d("Test", "Multiple SEND");
    }
```

The value of the imageUri is: content://media/external/images/media/37

But the function "openInputStream" throws the error "java.io.FileNotFoundException".

With the following function i get the real path of the image.

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But i don't know how to convert it to a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

A `Uri` is not a `File`. `new File(imageUri.toString())` is always wrong. `imageUri.getPath()` only works if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`, and in your case, the scheme is probably `content`.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the file or content identified by the `Uri`. Then, pass that stream to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`.

Also, please decode bitmaps on a background thread, so that you do not freeze your UI while this work is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I added this line:

"InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);"
But that line always throws the error "java.io.FileNotFoundException".

Comment: @WhatEver2337: What is the value of `imageUri`?

Comment: The value is: content://media/external/images/media/37

Comment: @WhatEver2337: That should be fine, though it may depend a bit on who is sending you that `Uri`. Consider asking a fresh Stack Overflow question -- or editing your existing one -- with your current code and the complete stack trace from the crash.

Comment: @WhatEver2337: I asked you to post your current code, the one that was crashing. You did not do this. I asked you to post the Java stack trace associated with the crash. You did not do this. And your `getRealPathFromUri()` will not work with many images from the `MediaStore`, let alone for any `Uri` that is *not* from the `MediaStore`.